# Transformer current peaks

Tags: current, transformer, transient

So I am designing a power supply, got everything calculated, and decided to simulate it for a second to see if the smoothing caps keep the voltage above the regulator limit at max current draw. What I noticed, that the current through the transformer peaks to nearly 2.5 amps when the cap is charging in the transformer.

[image: Simulation]

Will it destroy my 300mA transformer?

Comment: btw. what did you use to simulate it?

Comment: This online simulator: http://www.falstad.com/circuit/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well done!. You have identified a real world effect that many people are unaware of and that can cause significant problems. As well as the undesirable effect of the current spikes on capacitor ripple current (causing reduced lifetime) and possible transformer heating, the sudden current peaks cause RFI (Radio Frequency Interference) from the diodes. Power supplies with too low a primary DC resistance can be RF noise sources! Who would have thought ? :-).

The solution is easy but counterintuitive.
You need "spreading resistance" to increase the capacitor charging resistance. This adversely affects supply "regulation", as Vout drops with increasing load due to the resistor, but a compromise resistor value greatly improves results without too much effect on the regulation. If you are supplying an electronic regulator with this circuit then the drop caused by the resistor can be designed to have no effect at all on Vout, as it simply reduces regulator "headroom" slightly.

Add a small series resistor in the bridge to capacitor lead.
When the bridge voltage rises above Vcap, the higher the current would have been, the greater the drop in the resistor which raises the apparent value of the capacitor voltage temporarily.

Assuming you have about 15VDC peak and want 12 VDC out you have 2V or 3 V headroom. If Ipeak_usual is 300 mA then to drop say 0.5V in the resistor at 300 mA it would have a value of R=V/I = 0.5V/0.3A = 1.66 Ohms. Say 2 Ohms for convenience.

Clearly the prior 2.5A peak is now impossible.
At 2.5A the 2 Ohm resistor would drop V=IR = 2.5 x 2 = 5V and once the capacitor is at working voltage, there is not 5V of "headroom" to drive it.
By changing the R value and looking at the resultant current waveform you can choose a value which is large enough to "spread the conduction angle of the diodes, and small enough to limit the voltage drop as load current increases.

Long long ago undergraduates were given this problem to solve with capacitor value and desired peak diode current as parameters. Without 'modern aids' it was a nasty iterative problem and a good introduction to the real world. Ask me how I know :-).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will simulate some more and change the design accordingly!

Comment: @Limiter - you're welcome. I'd be interested to see/here what sort of results you get and how much it improves things. What values are Vtransformer and Vout. Does this feed a regulator?

Comment: This will feed a 7809, indeed, I will try to simulate this again, and update with results and numbers

Comment: I did some additional simulations, turns out the maximum resistance value can be 1.5R to supply the required 11.5V  for the 7809 at about 270mA, which will reduce the peaks to 1.19A through the transformer. Fortunately it is an unlikely scenario, and it seems I can use 1W resistors. At 100mA current draw it is more like 600mA peaks, which should be much more manageable.

Comment: Also Vtransformer is 12V RMS thus 16.9V peak. Diode bridge drop is 1.1V

Comment: Also I realised I simulated without any resistance through the transformer secondary, I will measure that as well before assembling.

Comment: A DClink inductor helps as well

Answer (score 2):

The peaks are not particularly important, especially for the transformer. What's important is the RMS current (for heating of the copper). Can you get your simulator to disgorge the RMS current? If you are using silly low rated diodes the peak current might be important, but I've done some pretty aggressive things with small diodes. If it's 1N400x/Mx then they're fine.

In the case of an ideal voltage source (and ideal diodes) the current is limited by the dV/dt of the input waveform into the capacitor. That's a **really** pessimistic value.

Suggest you try to measure the regulation of your 300mA transformer and insert an equivalent resistor into your simulation. It's not unusual for a transformer to drop in voltage by 20% or more under full load, which would imply a source resistance of around 8 ohms.

In reality, you should be absolutely fine without doing anything.

The RFI that Russell refers to is typically due to the reverse recovery snap-off of the rectifier diodes and can be mitigated with 10n caps across the diodes (often used in audio circuits).